# Performimg image processing and save image with same compression factor using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, imagemagick, jpeg

I can read an Image's metadata and find the image quality with the following command in linux, which I think is from ImageMagick:

```
identify -verbose image.jpg
```

The output of this command is the following:

```
...
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
**Quality: 96**
...
```

The important thing to me is to find which compression factor was used to generate the JPEG file. So, I have questions regarding these metadata:

1- Is the image quality the same as the JPEG compression factor used? if no, how can I find which compression factor was used to compress an JPEG image?

2- Can I do this with matlab?

Comment: Two things: ***(1)*** If you are up to some serious processing, you should not trust that `**Quality: 96**` info at all. It is just an entry in the metadata of the JPEG. I've come across various JPEG files in the past where this `Quality` was not correct at all. ***(2)*** The `Quality` thingie is not a standardized setting for JPEG generators. Each one interprets it different.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Ok, but is there any linux command that shows the compression factor used to generate the .JPEG file?

Comment: The metadata info in the `Quality:` entry is the closest info that is related to 'compression factor' you have in mind. But as I said: it is completely reliable. Some tools don't write anything into the metadata, so the old entry may just remain unchanged after JPEG->JPEG conversion. Also, after repeatedly doing a JPEG->JPEG conversion with *'quality 90", it will still have the same *'90'* entry, even though it is no more true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab, you can get the value of the quality factor of an image file with [`imfinfo`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html) (see the example).

**Edit**: However, the Quality is given in the `Comment` field, which can be filled differently depending on the software(s) that processed / generated your image. A more reliable method for you would be to use your unix command. In Matlab, you can type:

```
[~,res] = unix('identify -verbose image.jpg');
```

and `res` will contain the output from the command line (the exact same than what you obtain with your unix shell). You can then display it or parse it, as you like.

Then, it is also possible to save an image array to a JPG file at a given quality after some processing, with the function [`imwrite`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html?searchHighlight=imwrite). The command will look like:

```
imwrite(A,'myFile.jpg', 'Quality', 96);
```

You can also specify the `CodingMethod` and the `CodingProcess`.

So yes, it is possible !

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the output of imfinfo does not show the quality of thejpeg image. Take a look:

 Filename: '/home/anselmo/Diesel.jpg'
        FileModDate: '03-Mar-2015 20:06:53'
           FileSize: 50976
             Format: 'jpg'
      FormatVersion: ''
              Width: 443
             Height: 747
           BitDepth: 24
          ColorType: 'truecolor'
    FormatSignature: ''
    NumberOfSamples: 3
       CodingMethod: 'Huffman'
      CodingProcess: 'Progressive'
            Comment: {}
           Software: 'Picasa'
      DigitalCamera: [1x1 struct]

Comment: Yes, in the example of the `imfinfo` page the Quality is encoded in the `Comment` filed, which is filled differently by each software. See my edit for a different approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the res variable is a very big char. Can you help me extracting the exact part of the char where the 'quality' info is displayed?

Comment: Have a look at the function `textscan`, it is a good start for parsing. If you don't succeed on your own, you can ask another question on this precise issue, which is quite different from the initial topic.

Comment: @mad: or `strfind`, indeed. gook luck !